# How to control Default parameters in python

Tags: python-3.x

Default parameters are parameters, which don't have to be given if the function is called. In this case, the default values are used but I don't understand what happens if I have 2 default values. For example

```
def compare_two_numbers(first_input=2, second_input=3): 

if first_input != second_input:

    return "Different"

else:

    return "Same"

print(compare_two_numbers(3))
```

This compares 3 with 3. but what if I want the first to be default and I want to tell the program what the second one is what do I put inside here 
print(compare_two_numbers(?))

Comment: `print(compare_two_numbers(second_input=3))`

Comment: You can not control it, you have to choose and analyze which one you want.

Comment: Thank you, this explains what I was trying to do:)